# Return Data from Restangular Promises

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have factory looks like this:

```
MyApp.factory("Hello", function(Restangular, $q){
var theConfig = function() {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   Restangular.one('AllSettings').get().then(function(data){
       var theData = return {
          config1: data.config1,
          config2: data.config2
       }
       deferred.resolve(data);
   });

   return deferred.promise;
   };
    return{
        config : theConfig()
    };
});
```

I already using deffered, but it's still not return the object that needs to execute.
How to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are returning is a promise, not the actual data passed into `deferred.resolve`. Are you accessing the data like this?

```
MyApp.controller('WhateverController', function(Hello) {
  Hello.config.then(function(data) {
    // Do something with the data passed to deferred.resolve
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, My goal is return whatever in theData variable, so, I expected I can access like: Hello.config.config1, any suggestion?